# Will %= get the module of a collection?

Tags: c#

This is what I have so far to get the modulus of the collection that is being passed into the Mod method.

```
public static void Mod(int[] nums)
{
    int total = 0;
    foreach (int num in nums)
    {
        if (total == 0)
        {
            total = num;
        }
        else
        {
            total %= num;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Mod: " + total);
}
```

What I am wondering if this is the correct way to find this or will I get the totally wrong answer with this.

Comment: Are you getting the correct answer with this code ? Can you share some sample input and expected output ?

Comment: By "mod of a collection" do you mean "mod of the sum of the collection"? I'm unsure what result you're hoping for.

Comment: What's "the modulus of a collection"?  The modulus is the remainder after division (for example, 11%3 is 2 (11/3*3 is 9, 11-9 is 2).  I've never seen it used with more than a pair of numbers.  Now, I've never had the urge to use the %= operator (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/remainder-assignment-operator); it seems like something odd to me.  What you are doing is walking though a collection - geez, I can't even describe what your code does.  Do you have a definition of what you'd like to end up with?

Comment: I asked this question before actually testing it, that is my bad. I got what I expected thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer your question; yes, you will get the correct result; so long as you are expecting the result to be the remainder of the remainder of the remainder, and so on for the length of the array. In this respect, I agree with `flydog57's` comment:

> *Now, I've never had the urge to use the `%=` [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/remainder-assignment-operator); it seems like something odd to me.*

We all know that `x %= y` is the same as `x = x % y`; and it is in this exact use-case that we can use `%=` to simplify code. If you are asked to perform sequential modulus (get the remainder of 90 / 72, then get the remainder of that remainder), then your solution is correct. However, if your problem isn't sequential modulus, then please update your question to clarify.

On another note, your code can be simplified and improved:

```
public static int Mod(int[] nums) {
    int result = nums[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < nums.Length; i++) {
        // Division of zero is zero, and division by zero is only allowed with doubles.
        if (result == 0 || nums[i] == 0)
            return 0;

        result %= nums[i];
    }

    return result;
}

public static void Main(string[] args) {
    int[] nums = new int[] { 300, 205, 90, 72, 15, 6 };
    Console.WriteLine($"Result: {Mod(nums)}");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The above code will result in `5`, so perform your math with the values you need and see if the answer matches what you expect. If it doesn't, please update your question with your values and expected answers.